# remove r n r n from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, data-extraction

I want to remove extra r and n from this string. I tried regex. Not sure if regex or some other method would be helpful here.

This is the code I am trying to use   import re

```
text = "r n r n r nFamily Medical History new r n  r n r r r  Roger nRobert n nDawson n49 nyears old , right shoulder"

regex_pattern = re.compile(r'\s[rn]\s')
matches = regex_pattern.findall(text)
for match in matches:
    text = text.replace(match," ")
print(text)
```

Current Output:

```
r nFamily Medical History new   Roger nRobert nDawson n49 nyears old , right shoulder
```

we still see  many r n.  Also wondering how to remove 'n' from n49, nyears and remove first 'n' from Dawson without removing last 'n'

Expected Output:

```
Family Medical History new Roger Robert Dawson 49 years old , right shoulder
```

Comment: Where did you get this string from? Clearly the source of the problem is that what was originally `\r` and `\n`, became `r` and `n`. Did you do a replacement on that string that is responsible for this?

Comment: How would you differentiate `new` and `nDawson`?

Comment: Do you know the logic of how the r's and n's are being added to the string? For instance, always 3 blank lines then "Family Medical History new", then 5 blank lines? Is this consistent in all scenarios?

Comment: so I will answer you all guys. This is the string we have got. I just want to know how to remove 'n from 'nDawson' , 'n49', 'nyears'. I know it is little complicated logic wise

Comment: `string.replace('n49', '49').replace('nDawson', 'Dawson').replace('nyears', 'years')`, would work to remove the `n`, but this only work for those cases. I am not sure you can easily generalize this for all cases, but for `nDawson` you can check `n` with a capitalized letter, for `nyears` the directly replacing solution will probably work, for `n49` you might to try replacing `n\d+` with `\d+`.

Comment: try to split by whitespaces and then check everywords (old school)

Comment: text = "nFamily n49 new nTom"

I am trying to remove n from the above string using  re.compile(r'.*n[A-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]*\s') but not much success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a bit of an NLP approach here as I do not see how regex can tell `nyears` (wrong spelling) from `new` (correct spelling).

First, remove all standalone `r` / `n` and those glued to capitalized words and numbers, then split the string and check each word that starts with `n` or `r` with a spellchecker. The first `n` can be removed if `word[1:]` is correct and `word` is not. If both are not correct, I think it is safe to fallback to the `word`.

To run spellcheck, for example, you can use [`TextBlob`](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#spelling-correction).

Here is a Python code demo:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from textblob import Word
import re

s = "r n r n r nFamily Medical History new r n  r n r r r  Roger nRobert n nDawson n49 nyears old , right shoulder"
s = re.sub(r'\b[rn](?=[A-Z0-9\s]|$)', '', s)
result = []
for w in s.split():
  if not w.startswith(('n','r')): # The w word does not start with n or r...
    result.append(w)              # Add it to the result
  else:
    if Word(w).correct() == w:    # If w is a correct word
      result.append(w)            # Add it to the result
    else:
      if Word(w[1:]).correct() == w[1:]: # If w[1:] is correct 
        result.append(w[1:])             # Add w[1:] to the result
      else:
        result.append(w)                 # Fallback: add w to the result
print(" ".join(result))
# => Family Medical History new Roger Robert Dawson 49 years old , right shoulder
```

The `re.sub(r'\b[rn](?=[A-Z0-9\s]|$)', '', s)` part remove `r` and `n` at the start of words if immediately followed with an uppercase letter, digit or end of string.

Then, `for w in s.split():` iterates over the words in the sentence and replaces the word only in case it starts with `n` or `r` and has a spelling error with `w[1:]`.

**DISCLAIMER**: `TextBlob` is used as an example. You are free to use any other spellchecking library. [TextBlob spellchecking](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#spelling-correction) "*is based on Peter Norvig’s “How to Write a Spelling Corrector”[1](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#spelling-correction) as implemented in the pattern library. It is about 70% accurate*"

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this `\b[rn](?=[A-Z0-9 ])`

The `\b` looks for any work boundary (start of the string, spaces, newlines).

The `[rn]` looks for either 'r' or 'n'

The `(?=[A-Z0-9 ])` looks for any uppercase, space, or number but does not include them in the match.

Checkout https://regex101.com/r/hSmYyi/1 for messing around with regexes and for testing.

Comment: This does not work since the `nyears` [remains unchanged](https://regex101.com/r/hSmYyi/1).

Comment: Good catch! Back to the old drawing board, I guess the lookahead could be changed to `(?=[A-Z0-9 ]|years)` but that feels like cheating.

Comment: Right, I also had the same thought, that is why I think the words that start with `n` followed with a lowercase letter can be spellchecked first, and `n` can be removed if `word[1:]` is a valid word and `word` is not.

Comment: That would be a clever way around the issue. A little more involved programmatically, but would work for pretty much anything.

Comment: re.compile(r'\s[rn]\s')  re.sub(r'\b[rn](?=[A-Z\d])', "", text)

I am using these two regex two deal with the problem

Comment: Added [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65852099/3832970) that also utilizes the updated version of this regex.

Answer (score 0):

**Old school** over here

```
>>> text = "r n r n r nFamily Medical History new r n  r n r r r  Roger nRobert n nDawson n49 nyears old , right shoulder"
>>> newText = []
>>> for word in text.split(' '):
...     if word and not (word == 'n' or word =='r'):
...         if not word[0] == 'n':
...             newText.append(word)
...         else:
...             newText.append(word[1:])
... 
>>> newText
['Family', 'Medical', 'History', 'ew', 'Roger', 'Robert', 'Dawson', '49', 'years', 'old', ',', 'right', 'shoulder']
>>> ' '.join(newText)
'Family Medical History ew Roger Robert Dawson 49 years old , right shoulder'
>>>
```

of course you can refactoring it as you pleasure.